# Special characters using Odata Webservice

Tags: odata, java

i'm trying to make some queries to Tridion using OData Webservice. I'm having troubles using filters that contains single quote (`'`) or other charactes like (`á,ü,ç,ñ,...`).

For example:

```
http://......./cd_webservice/odata.svc/Keywords?$filter=Description eq 'Gare centrale d'Utrecht'
```

I tried doubling single quotes, changing single quotes for double quotes, changing single quotes for (%27) character, encoding previously characters using java class URLEncoder and it doesn't work.

I need to know how to escape correctly these characters in Java because every query fails if contains this characters.

Comment: Have you tried using `&apos;` ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226544%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Comment: Hello Nuno, &apos; is used to escape XML characters, however i try it but it not works. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to escape the single quote in OData service url is to ***update your search text with two single quotes*** instead of one. You have to manually or through code has to change the search text. eg. 'Gare centrale d''Utrecht'

```
 http://......./cd_webservice/odata.svc/Keywords?$filter=Description eq 'Gare centrale d''Utrecht'
```

Comment: That's also my understanding, but I wonder if he already tried that ("I tried doubling single quotes..."). It's also worth noting that some languages (and therefore keyboard layouts) use different single quotes -- so you will want to make sure you are using the ASCII one.

Comment: hmmm. that annoying ` vs '

Comment: Hello, im using character ' encoded as char %27 in a URL.
I try using two single quotes instead one but does not work.
As example i try the request   http://......./cd_webservice/odata.svc/Keywords?$filter=Description eq 'Gare centrale d''Utrecht'
and the result is: 
<message xml:lang="en-US">Filter syntax error near value: 'Gare centrale d'</message>